# Confusion about an email reply

Tags: email, north-american-english

I am an undergraduate student. I was applying to transfer to another university. I wrote to a university official requesting some information, and here is the conversation:

Me: ask if the college still accepts transfer students this year, and ask what materials are required for the application (where I listed some required materials I found on their website).

The official: says the college still accepts transfer students and asks what is my major.

Me: math.

The official: asks what courses I have completed.

Me: list some courses.

The official: "Seems like you would be in a good position as far as the math major goes."

---

I really don't understand the last sentence. Is the official implying that I am doing ok in my current university, and asking for the reason for applying? Or is the person saying that the courses I've taken have met their requirements and therefore I am eligible to apply as a transfer student?

Comment: i.e. they approve of your application. No worries. As far as the others, they are in doubt. That's what I read into the complete statement. Maybe there is more context?

Comment: @Cascabel no. Those were the entire correspondence.

Comment: @GoogleME, as a general matter, when somebody sends you an unclear e-mail message, it is **much** better to seek a clarification from that person than from third parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are saying that your desire to apply as a transfer student is reasonable.  If you hadn't taken any math courses, they might have suggested a different approach that would work better for your situation (such as just applying as a regular new student).

Answer (score 1):

Translation: You got a strongly hinted  **Yes**.

More than eligible to apply as a transfer student, you are being welcomed to apply along the regular channels. It's not an English thing, but a bureaucrat will not say directly "You are in! I admit you right now!" since it's not up to one 'university official' but the Admissions Committee.

Instead, "Seems like you would be in a good position" implies strongly that your **record looks good for admission** as a Math major here, **but no promises.**

- Note the hedging term of *Seems like* (= Oh yeah, I think, probably, I see it that way at this moment in time perhaps, looks good without my reading glasses. And most of all: don't blame me or even quote me).
- Note the non-committal sense of *would be in a good position* (= In some world, hypothetically if you don't go and bet on it, all other facts being euphemistic).
- Note the self-protective *as far as* (= Only to the extent that the sky is blue and no more).